# Set background and hover over image on button

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have 8 buttons on my WPF Page (C# application).
For each of these buttons I want a different image placed onm them and also a hover over image.

This link tells me how to place a background image for all the buttons: [wpf button background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4099500/wpf-button-background-image)

How can I modify this so that each button has its own unique background image and hover over image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case different image is required, you have to set Background Image and hover image `differently for each button`.

Moreover, `hover over image won't be visible` because default mouse over brush of button will always override background of button. For that you have to `override default template` which can be done in default Style of button.

Like mentioned in example below for one button, you need to replicate that for other buttons. (**No need to override default template since it will be applied automatically for all buttons. Just inner style you need to provide for other 7 buttons.**)

```
<StackPanel>
   <StackPanel.Resources>
      <Style TargetType="Button">
         <Setter Property="Template">
           <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
               <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                  <ContentPresenter/>
               </Border>
             </ControlTemplate>
           </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
       </Style>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <Button Width="100" Height="100">
      <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button"
               BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
           <Setter Property="Background">
             <Setter.Value>
               <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image1.png"/>
             </Setter.Value>
           </Setter>
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver,
                                         RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                          Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background">
                  <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Image2.png"/>
                  </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
              </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </Button.Style>
   </Button>
</StackPanel>
```